# React Component not working properly with Mapbox

Tags: reactjs, single-page-application, create-react-app, mapbox-gl-js, react-component

I'm new on React, but due to requirements at an assigment in college, I must use it . I must do a single page application (SPA), with various components. I used **npx create-react-app** to setup the base project, and so you have an idea, it looks like this right now:

[image]

Each functionality such as "create new node", "create new line", etc, is an individual component.

On my **App.js**, I'm setting a state for each component as false, only making it true when the key of the submenu associated with that specific component is clicked, allowing me to switch between the sidebar options with no problem, and then at each component, I have *display: false* at the state and also this:

```js
componentWillUpdate(nextprops) {
    if (nextprops.display !== this.props.display) {
      this.setState({ display: nextprops.display });
    }
  }
```

so it makes that display true, so that component is loaded. Everything works nicely, only the *map viewer* has a problem where the map by **mapboxgl** displays in full screen, covering the sidebar, not allowing me to change between components. The MapViewer component code is:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import mapboxgl from "mapbox-gl";
//import 'mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.css'
mapboxgl.accessToken="MY_KEY_IS_HERE";

class MapViewerComp extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      longitude: -8.562298,
      latitude: 41.187181,
      zoom: 12,
      display: false,
    };
  }

  componentWillUpdate(nextprops) {
    if (nextprops.display !== this.props.display) {
      this.setState({ display: nextprops.display });
    }
  }

  displayTheMap = () => {
    const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: "root",
      style: "mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11",
      center: [this.state.longitude, this.state.latitude],
      zoom: this.state.zoom
    });
    
    var marker = new mapboxgl.Marker().setLngLat([-8.562298, 41.187181]).addTo(map);
  };

  render() {
    let pageContent = <div></div>;
    if (this.state.display) {
      pageContent = (
        <div>
          <div ref={this.displayTheMap} className="mapContainer"/>
        </div>
      );
    }
    return <div>{pageContent}</div>;
  }
}

export default MapViewerComp;
```

And the .css looks like this:

```css
.ant-switch-handle {
    text-align: right;
}
.mapContainer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

When I click the "Map Viewer" option on my sidebar (which corresponds to my (MapViewerComp), it pops out like this:

[image]

Since I'm new to React and frontend, the only was I was able to force it to fit my screen like this:

[image]

was to add this piece to the .css of this component:

```css
.mapboxgl-canvas{
  position: absolute;
  left: 271px;
  top: 65px;
}
```

The 2 problems are:
1st: if I force it to the size I want like I showed you, now when I zoom in and out on the map, the marker moves around and doesn't stay in place.
2nd: when I click the other options on the sidebar, to switch between functionalities, it doesn't work, it keeps showing the map.

The code of the index.js at **src**(with the npx create-react-app structure) is:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './components/app/App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
reportWebVitals();
```

And the code for the index.html on **public** folder is:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000"/>
    <meta name="description" content="Web site created using create-react-app"/>
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png"/>
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json"/>
    <script src="../src/components/mapViewerComp/MapViewerComp.js"></script>
    <link href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.13.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

here's the structure of the project as well if it helps in any way:

[image]

Any fix to any of the issues would be appreciated. All other components work like a charm, yet the map viewer is not...
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Turns out the mapbox is set to render inside of the app root container, which why it is taking all the available space and not going away when re-rendering the app. Setting margins exposes the sidebar and allows to interact with it but alas doesn't trigger the map to go away.

[See the doc here.](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/fitbounds/)

Comment: Hi Théophile, thank you for taking the time. I updated my MapViewerComp.js file (you can re-check it above if needed), and now my page content is like this:
```
<div class="map-container">
     <div class="map">ref={this.displayTheMap}</div>
</div>
```
Now it fits the part I want, and I can navigate to other components on the side bar, yet, it only shows a big yellow area where the map should be, is my calling of the **displayTheMap** function wrong? I tried with *ref=* but still doesn't work. Thank you again and sorry for being so newbie on this

Comment: Oh that's because you copied the `background-color` property :) I included it just to demonstrate how the div behaves with those properties but you should delete it, sorry I forgot to mention that! I think what happens is that the background-color overrides the map because it's a background in itself!

Comment: Basically just delete this line: `background-color: #ffbb00;`

Comment: I've updated the demo if you just want to copy-paste it again: https://codepen.io/theophilelouvel/pen/vYXEBNe

Comment: Adding background colors to a `<div>` is just a very common way of visually checking how it will behave with a set of given properties, otherwise you can never be really sure how much space it takes and how it works out in your global structure, it's a useful thing to do when you're working on your layout :)

Comment: I've removed the background-color, and it doesn't change anything, now it doesn't show anything when I click at MapViewer, it's just a blank screen. Everything you said made perfect sense, I was excited and thought it would work, yet it just made everything white... I've tried about everything, but sadly the problem is my lack of knowledge regarding this. (Also, the demo seemed the same)

Comment: Any chance you could make a .zip of your project (deleting the node modules folder first) and send me a download link like from Google Drive for instance? At this point we're just guessing around but without the source code it's going to be hard to help in a meaningful way :/ I still think it's just an html/css problem, but providing a solution might require some playing around with properties to see where the problem comes from

Comment: The next thing I would try though is to add `flex: 1` in your css to the map `<div>` (is this the `mapboxgl-canvas`?) itself (not the container) to see if it's not just shrinking because of some other properties. Again, I just updated the demo with that

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/10ZKaLMsl080Ya_N3PIM_r1Uc9BAWaG4a/view?usp=sharing

Here's the link, I didn't send the backend API, that is what allows the frontend to create the post requests and such because it's pointless for what we're trying, so I just sent the SPA. I thank you so SO much buddy, i have no words!

Comment: Just for fun, this is the best css explanation you'll ever get  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aub7SE8OJEJn_g-ddGJWlljG6UrMl5wN/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hey buddy, I think you've added **.mapboxgl-canvas** yes? Like I said in my original post, I used that as well to force it to the corner, the problem as you might now test, is that once you click on the map side menu option, you can never ever go back. All others you can toogle between them, but once you pick the map option, it doesn't go back :c Sorry Théophile, your help is being precious as you're my best chance atm /: As I stated in the post, the problem with **.mapboxgl-canvas** is not allowing me to click the other menus :c

Comment: So if mapbox is set to render inside the app root container, is this task impossible to do? It's weird because all of these tutorials and the [doc](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/fitbounds/) you mention, all have small maps on small windows, fitting perfectly on a page, and that's exactly what was expected of us... I just talked to most of my colleagues and they're all struggling, some of them gave up and are now on a desperate attempt to use harp.gl

Comment: Yes but as you can see all those example set the container another dom element, map in the case of the link I've attached. The problem is that the root container doesn't go away since it's the app container, it's a html hierarchy problem. The second thing is I see you used some kind of templating package that doesn't expose the html structure, so I'm not even sure what you should set the container to. Usually the best approach is to have a `<body><div class="sidebar"></div><div class="content"></div></body>` structure so you can target content without overriding all your app.

Comment: Maybe if you look into the documentation of antd you'll find some useful information about what's the container called